# how to use array of string as condition in Drools decision table?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-flow

I am new to drools decision table, so my question may be invalid.
In my decision table i am using "in" in condition column.
Exampe : i have  class  Student and there is another class UniversityConstant.
In UniversityConstant class there is array of string subject code : public static final String[] subjectCode ={"150","920","930","940","154"};
[image]

In this case my condition not working properly(Above picture: Not working). Instead of using string array constant of java class  if i use direct subject code string than it is working(Below picture:working).

[image]

In my project there are lots of string array ,so it is not possible to copy paste them in decision table excel. Even in case i use string constant in UniversityConstant class  which represent all subject code like public static final String subjectCodeStr1 ="\"155\",\"920\",\"930\",\"940\",\"154\"" OR
                public static final String subjectCodeStr2 ="155,920,930,940,154"; than also it is not working. My question is there any way to use string array constant or simple string which represents array of string of java 
in decision table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the constant sets as

```
public static final List<String> subjectCodes =
  Arrays.asList( "155","920","930","940","154" );
```

and use

```
...getPrimarySub() memberOf $param
...
UniversityConstamt.subjectCodes
```

Comment: Don't send thanks, but accept the answer so people know the status. - Read the Drools documentation. - Not specific to decision tables, but probably useful: google "Design Patterns in Production Systems", should be located on a redhat.com page.